# In how many ways one can arrange the numbers $0,1,2,\dots,n$ using each number exactly once so that no two adjacent numbers sum greater than $n+1$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recreational-mathematics

> Given the numbers $0,1,2,\dots,n$. In how many ways one can arrange the numbers using each number exactly once so that no two adjacent numbers sum greater than $n+1$?

I found the answers for small values of $n$. For $n=1$, the answer is $2$. For $n=2$, the answer is $6$. For $n=3$, the answer is $12$. But how to solve this problem for any $n$?

Comment: related: https://oeis.org/A026549

Comment: This is a generalization of [this very recent Mathematics SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4370524/26369) from the Bangladesh Mathematical Olympiad and [this other one with a different number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4369710/26369).

Answer (score 0):

See [Number of Ways of Ordering Numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4370524/number-of-ways-of-ordering-numbers/4370610#4370610).

The solution is $6^k$ for $n=2k$ and $2.6^k$ for $n=2k+1$.